# Unix process running python

Tags: python, linux, process

I have a cron who execute 2 python scripts. How I can see with the "ps" command if the process are running ?

my scripts names are:

json1.py
json2.py

Answer (score 0):

`ps aux | grep json` ought to do it, or just `pgrep -lf json`.

Comment: I would say `ps -ef | grep json`